# Login screen appears damaged

Tags: graphics, login-screen

This is what I got instead of login screen in Ubuntu 20.04 :
[image: login screen]

When I blindly type the password, it will login into the system, and there is no problem after that. The problem seems to be only with login screen.

My graphics card : MGA G200eH3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. It will then ask you for your username. Type in your username. It will then ask you for your password. Type in your password. You are using a virtual terminal when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Same thing happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>-6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> brings you back to the GUI.

Try running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in the virtual terminal. You might have to run `sudo apt install lightdm` Then select the option that you aren't using. After that, do `sudo shutdown now -r`. That will restart your PC. It should work now. If it still doesn't work, follow the steps in the 1st paragraph, then go to the 4th paragraph.

After you reboot and are in the virtual terminal again, type `sudo lightdm` or `sudo`  followed by the other option the sudo dpkg-reconfigure, then follow the step in the 2nd paragraph. The login screen should be there now.

Comment: `lightdm` is not used by default in Ubuntu 20.04.  And TTY1 and TTY2 are used by the GUI now, not 6 and 7.  This looks like it was written for a version *older* than what OP is asking about

Comment: The problem solved after I changed my display manager from gdm3 to lightdm. I don't know whether that is recommended with ubuntu 20.04